# Fonts not showing for desktop layout. Why?

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

I have css that is setting font icon content
[image]

On mobile it shows fine here:

[image]

But on desktop it is not showing:

[image]

It's the same layout, the css is loaded, the icons are loaded.  What is happening?

Comment: do you use any theme?

Comment: please inspect that element, check in style section if there is anything similar like display:none or visibility:hidden